# Jbuttons stucked when i play mp3 file

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mp3, jlayer

I'm trying to make an mp3 player using swing and when i play a song my jbutton play stays stucked and i can't press any other buttons from my app.I tried to use threads and it didn't worked, here is my play function code.

```
    public static void fplay() 
{
    Runnable fplay = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!songs.isEmpty())
            {
                for(int j=0;j<songs.size();j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(path+"\\"+songs.get(j));
                    file = new File(path+"\\"+songs.get(j));
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        player = new AdvancedPlayer(fis);
                        graphics.label.setText(songs.get(j).toString());
                        player.play();
                    }catch(Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }else 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No directory selected","Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }};
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(fplay);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i play a song my jbutton play stays stucked and i can't press any other buttons from my app

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(fplay);
```

The invokeLater(...) method adds code to the end of `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So this means the audio is still executing on the `EDT` and the GUI can't respond to events.

Instead you need to start a separate `Thread`, so the audio doesn't prevent the GUI from responding to events.

So you want to pass the `Runnable` to a `Thread` and start the `Thread`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT.

> I tried to use threads and it didn't worked

Well, that is the proper solution. I can't guess what you did wrong, although you should never have an empty catch block. How will you know what the error is if you don't display anything?

The tutorial on `Concurrency` also shows how to use a SwingWorker which could be a better solution for you.